# JavaFX fill a table view not possible

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, populate

I just started with javafx and I wanted to create a `TableView` with 3 columns where I can display some values.
I created the `TableView` and the columns with the scene editor as fxml file.
Then I created a class named `Values` with the special properties I matched to the columns where they should fit in.
Finally I set the observable list with the "Value" objects in it as items of the table. When I start the application, it only shows me an empty table.
I looked like 4 hours in the internet now and still not found an answer why this is not working for me.

Here my code:

Value Class:

```
public class Values {
    public  SimpleDoubleProperty PSI = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
    public  SimpleDoubleProperty ALPHA = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
    public  SimpleDoubleProperty DELTA = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);

    public Values(Double _PSI, Double _ALPHA, Double _DELTA) {
        setPSI(_PSI);
        setALPHA(_ALPHA);
        setDELTA(_DELTA);
    }

    private void setPSI(Double p){
        PSI.set(p);
    }
    private void setALPHA(Double p){
        ALPHA.set(p);
    }
    private void setDELTA(Double p){
        DELTA.set(p);
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
@FXML Label psi;
@FXML Label alpha;
@FXML Label delta;


@FXML TextField betafield;
@FXML TextField lambdafield;
@FXML TextField lambdasatfield;

@FXML TableView<Values> table;
@FXML ObservableList<Values> oblist;
@FXML TableColumn <Values,Double> psicolumn;
@FXML TableColumn <Values,Double> alphacolumn;
@FXML TableColumn <Values,Double> deltacolumn;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    psicolumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Values, Double>("PSI"));
    alphacolumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Values, Double>("ALPHA"));
    deltacolumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Values, Double>("DELTA"));
}

@FXML
protected void buttonpressed(){
    try {
        Calculation cal = new Calculation(Double.parseDouble(betafield.getText()), Double.parseDouble(lambdafield.getText()), Double.parseDouble(lambdasatfield.getText()));
        alpha.setText("Alpha: " + " " + cal.calculateAlpha());
        delta.setText("Delta:"+ " " + cal.calculateDelta());
        psi.setText("Psi:"+ " " + cal.calculatePSI());
        table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(cal.calculateEvaluaiontable()));
    }catch (NullPointerException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And my FXML:

```xml
 <Tab text="tab" fx:id="tabe">
   <content>
     <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
         <children>
            <TableView layoutX="4.0" layoutY="4.0" prefHeight="192.0" prefWidth="370.0" fx:id="table">
                <columns>
                    <TableColumn prefWidth="120.0" text="PSI" fx:id="psicolumn" />
                    <TableColumn prefWidth="120.0" text="ALPHA" fx:id="alphacolumn" />
                    <TableColumn prefWidth="120.0" text="DELTA" fx:id="deltacolumn" />
                </columns>
            </TableView>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </content>
 </Tab>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need to have properly named value getters or property getters. See linked question for detailed answer.

Comment: @sillyfly thanks for your answer. i check the other topic and changed my code a bit, but it does not fix my issue

Comment: If you are certain you have value getters with the correct name and it still doesn't work please update your question with the corrected code.

Answer (score 2):

Let `<name>` denote the constructor parameter of [`PropertyValueFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html) and let `<Name>` denote the same `String`, but with an uppercase first letter.

`PropertyValueFactory` can get the value from one of the following sources:

1. The property getter, i.e. the a method `SomeObservableValue <name>Property()`.
2. The getter method, i.e. the method `SomeType get<Name>()`.

None of those exist in your `Values` class.

For the `psicolumn` to work, `Values` needs a `DoubleProperty PSIProperty()` method or a `double getPSI()` method. (Same issue with the other columns)

Comment: figured it out! thanks!